# CakePHP 3 Basic Auth - Not working once deployed

Tags: php, apache, authentication, cakephp, basic-authentication

I've got a **CakePHP 3** app that's using the built in **Basic Auth** for a JSON API we're building.

It's working fine locally (**MAMP**), and on **Jolt** hosting, but as soon as I deploy it to **Heart Internet** it won't authenticate. Almost as if it's forgetting, filtering, or rejecting the Basic Auth dialogue/header input.

Are there any specific dependencies or mods that I need to enable on the server? Heart's tech support are at a loss.

Any ideas where I can look for a solution? It simply keeps re-prompting for the auth, and the password is correct as I can log in to the web UI with it.

Server's a VPS running a standard **CentOS6** server with **cPanel**. Usual LAMP stack.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: please dump the whole request of every step of local and prod. Since you're using a Mac, always also keep in mind your production system is case-sensitive and your local machine isn't. Just as a "guess"

Comment: Hey there, sorry but what do you mean by "please dump the whole request of every step of.." ? ... I know about the case sensitivity, and it's not that, it works on another case sensitive server :( ... really stuck for a solution!